# Central Limit Theorem for a continuous variable?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Could someone please provide some explanation to the following question ?

Let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be independent random variables that are uniform in [0,1]; and let $S_{n} = X_{1} + ... + X_{n}$. Using the CLT, give an approximation of $P(S_{100} \subset [45,55])$.

The problem with me is that I know how to solve such problems in discrete cases (ie: flipping a coin or tossing a dice) but how would I apply this case since I believe that there can be a large number of values that $X_{1}$ can take on (correct me if I'm wrong).

So I am a little bit stuck and would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline:

The sum $S$ of $100$ iid $Unif(0,1)$ random variables will be very nearly normal.

Also, $E(S) = \mu = 100E(U) = 100(1/2) = 50$ and by independence 
$V(S) = \sigma^2 = 100V(U) = 100(1/12).$

So a reasonable approximation is 
$P\{(45-\mu)/\sigma < Z < (55-\mu)/\sigma\},$ where $Z$ is
standard normal.

Comment: Thank you, after standardizing, I got that $P(Z\leq \frac{3}{5}) - P(z \leq \frac{-3}{5}) = 0.7257 - 0.2257 = 0.4514$. Does that look correct, just to double check ? Appreciate your time

Comment: To standardize you need to divide by the SD not the variance. In R, I used code `diff(pnorm(c(45,55),50,sqrt(100/12)))` to get 0.9167355.

Comment: Oh shoot, that was such a careless error. Thank you for the correction